# while loop won't align and continue with code and keeps looping

Tags: python

I am trying to make a password checker program within Python (PyCharm), with given criteria, but for some odd reason, the while loop would end after the else statement. The criteria and code are given below:

- Cannot use a break
- password & password_length cannot be in the while

I've tried multiple solutions but the code seems to be causing the same problem. The code keeps looping around one message.

```
MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6  # Constants
MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 10
message = ''

password = input("Please enter your password: ")
password_length = len(password)

while message != "password strong":
    print(password_length)
    if password_length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH or password_length > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
        message = "Password should have more than 6 but less 10 characters"
    elif password.isalpha():
        message = "password weak – contains only letters"
    elif password.isnumeric():
        message = "password weak – contains only numbers"
    else:
        message = "password strong"
    print(message)
    if message == "password strong":
        exit()
```

Comment: by the way, these are password rules from the 1980s, don't do that – this would be training your users to use easy-to-bruteforce-or-easy-to-guess-from-modified-dictionaries passwords.

Comment: You're not asking for a new password if the initial password doesn't meet the criteria. The `input()` call needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: @MarcusMüller This looks like an exercise in how to write loops and if statements, not a security exercise.

Comment: And you don't need those last two statements.  If the message equals that, your `while` loop will immediately exit anyway.

Comment: @Barmar I'm fully aware, that's why the comments starts with a "by the way.."

Comment: Alain's answer should do the trick. But there is something very fishy with your requirements. If `password & password_length cannot be in the while`, there is no way for you to update your input on the password guess, so there seems to not be a real way to solve it in the same execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use user messages as internal indicators.  You should use a separate (boolean) variable.  The infinite loop is caused by the user prompt for a password being asked only once outside of the while loop.

Here is the adjusted code that I believe should work for you:

```
MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 6  # Constants
MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 10

passwordIsStrong = False  # password validity indicator, 
 
while not passwordIsStrong:
    password = input("Please enter your password: ") # (re)-ask for a password
    password_length = len(password)
    print(password_length)

    if password_length < MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH or password_length > MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH:
        message = "Password should have more than 6 but less 10 characters"
    elif password.isalpha():
        message = "password weak – contains only letters"
    elif password.isnumeric():
        message = "password weak – contains only numbers"
    else:
        message = "password strong"
        passwordIsStrong = True      # this will stop the loop
    print(message)
```